# Simple example AJAX submit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have looked everywhere for an example of submitting a form to the database using AJAX so that the page doesn't refresh and doesn't redirect, but have found nothing of use.  Can someone please help me out by showing a simple example using AJAX in Rails?  Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is submitting the form without having the page refresh/redirect, then you have to do this:

```
<%= form_tag('/yourfolder', :remote => true) do -%>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I'm looking for; but what should I put for '/yourfolder'? Is this is the folder of the model or the controller?  Right now this is what my form for tag looks like: <%= form_for [@season, @meet, @event], :remote => true, :html => { :mulitpart => true } do |f| %>

Comment: In that case, it should be form_for (@season, remote: true).

Answer (score 0):

For creating ajax based form submit you have to make change in form and controller ..i will suggest you to check out following article for on use of ajax in rails .that was very helpful for me also.

http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/ajaxify-your-site-with-remote-true/#.UzG4J0OJQ9c